# Random error thrown on downloading a file

Tags: vb.net

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this. If I click on the send button, it can't download the log.txt after that...

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1
Public sent As Boolean = False
Private Declare Function SHChangeNotify Lib "Shell32.dll" (ByVal wEventID As Int32, _
                                                           ByVal uFlags As Int32, _
                                                           ByVal dwitem1 As Int32, _
                                                           ByVal deitem2 As Int32) As Int32

Private Sub send_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles send.Click
    'If a message has been sent
    sent = True
    Try
        Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt")
        sent = False
        writer.Write(input.Text)
        Try
            Dim ftp As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp://***/c/log.txt"), FtpWebRequest)
            ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile
            Dim ftpResponse As FtpWebResponse = CType(ftp.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
            ftpResponse = ftp.GetResponse()
            ftpResponse.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt", New Uri("ftp://***/c/log.txt"), "user", "pass", False, 30000, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
        input.Text = ""
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    sent = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c")
    Else
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c", FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c")
    End If
    firstcheck()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
End Sub

Private Sub taskbarcheck_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles taskbarcheck.Tick
    If File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\chax.txt") Then
        Me.Opacity = 100
        Me.Show()
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\chax.txt")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        SHChangeNotify(&H8000000, &H1000, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_hide.Click
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\chax.txt")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Me.Opacity = 0
    Me.Hide()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    SHChangeNotify(&H8000000, &H1000, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub ftpstuff_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ftpstuff.Tick
    'Try
    'delete file if exists
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    'download file
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt")
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    'My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://***/c/log.txt", My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt", "", "", False, 30000, False)
    Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
    If Not sent = True Then
        myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://***/c/log.txt", My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt")
        log.Text = File.ReadAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub firstcheck()
    If Not File.Exists(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt") Then
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(New Uri("ftp://***/c/log.txt"), My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\c\log.txt", "user", "pass", False, 30000, True, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried it every way that i knew of... The "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll" is thrown when it tries to download the file after i click the send button.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Does the `WebException` have any `InnerException`?

Comment: I'm not home at the moment, but I'll take a look when I get back.

Comment: It says in the additional information: "An exception occurred during a WebClient request." I can't get it to write out the inner exception.. Prephaps I'm doing something wrong?  http://pastebin.com/zxiJjFUH

Comment: If you get an exception before the stream is closed, the code jumps straight to the catch block and the stream is never closed. I presume that the file is locked until the program terminates. Try closing the file in the catch block

Comment: Better still - for the time being comment out the three Try..Catch...End Try lines. Then run the program and you'll see any errors that happen - Try blocks are there for when you've written code to be robust against expected errors. Not really good for when you're developing the  app and trying to debug it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was the stream not closing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you get an exception before the stream is closed, the code jumps straight to the catch block and the stream is never closed. I presume that the file is locked until the program terminates.

Try adding a command to close the file in the `Catch` block as well as in your `Try` block